# AppArmor deny all files except specific

Tags: apparmor

I want a AppArmor profile which denies a binary access to all files except .so-files/libraries and specific directories which it need access to.

```
#include <tunables/global>

/home/test/rust-api/target/debug/python-executor flags=(complain) {
    # deny all outgoing network requests.
    deny network inet,
    deny network inet6,
    deny network tcp,
    deny network udp,

    #deny writing and executing all files.
    deny /** rwkx,
    
    # allow .sp files.
    allow /**.so*

    # allow files for smem and unixsockets.
    allow /home/test/rust-api/tmp/** rwk,
    allow /home/test/rust-api/tmp/sockets/** rwk,
    
    #allow reading python scripts in trading_algos.
    allow /home/test/rust-api/trading_algos/** r,
}
```

I thought I could just do `deny /** rwkx` to deny all files and later specify what files to allow. But still AppArmor denies access to all files.